# PHP post multipart form POST/FILE not working if more than about 15K bytes

Tags: php, post, multipartform-data

Ive spent hours on an iOS upload request to a PHP script trying to figure out why the _POST and _FILES values were empty at the PHP script side.

I finally figured out that anything I send *OVER* about 15K bytes (Content-Length) is the problem.  Anything under this amount shows my _POST and _FILES coming through as expected.  I also only sending 3 _POST vars and 1 File at a time.

My question is what variable(s) in my php.ini script might cause this?

I have the following php.ini variables set to:

```
post_max_size = 1M
file_uploads = On
max_file_uploads = 1
memory_limit = 40M
upload_max_filesize = 1M
```

Ive tried increasing each as well with the same result.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: sometimes (just sometimes) the issues are in the code itself. Show it ?

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the code and not php

Answer (score 0):

post_max_size = 1M and 
upload_max_filesize = 1M should be the options, check php_info if your changes has been loaded

maybe this is server setting, in apache there is directive LimitRequestBody for that

Comment: That was the issue, I had LimitRequestBody set too low.  Thank you!